# React настройка meta tags

Tags: reactjs, meta

Как правильно вставлять мета теги.
Использую Helmet прописываю допустим title, descriptiom, в инспекторе вижу. Когда проверяю через сервис, их не видно, видно только те что в index.html стандартные (react)

Comment: через какой сервис проверяете?

Comment: https://involta.ru/tools/meta-tags-checker/
а так через любой